# Will my wake up alarm ring all day? I left it at work

Tags: alarm

I left my phone at work in my locker, Im not in work today, will my wake up alarm (that I have on repeat mon-fri) sound off all day on repeat or does it stop after a few attempts?

Comment: It probably depends on the app you're using, but Google's Clock app will stop ringing after a while and leaving "missed alarm" notification instead.